# Can there be more than one zero morphism between two objects?

Tags: category-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Category with zero morphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189818/category-with-zero-morphisms)

Given two objects $X,Y$ in a category, can there be more than one zero morphism $X\rightarrow Y$?

Comment: In an answer to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189818/category-with-zero-morphisms), Qiaochu already indicated that there is a unique zero morphism between any two objects.

Comment: @Zhen Lin, I think what Qiaochu showed was that for a given category, if there is a "collection" of zero morphisms satisfying certain property then that collection is unique. Here I'm talking about "a" zero morphism in the sense that it is both constant morphism and coconstant morphism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of a zero morphism as a morphism that is both constant and coconstant is not a very useful one. Zero morphisms make much more sense in a category with a zero object – since in that case they can be defined to be the unique morphism that factors through the zero object. Under *that* definition, they are unique.

In the absence of a zero object, stupid things can happen. For example, consider the category $\{ \bullet \rightrightarrows \bullet \}$ with exactly two parallel non-identity arrows. It is essentially vacuous that both of the non-identity arrows are constant and coconstant – but they are distinct by hypothesis.